What does the verb advantage mean in this sentence from chapter one of "Wuthering Heights"?
In the first chapter of Wuthering Heights Emily Brontë writes:

The apartment and furniture would have been nothing extraordinary as belonging to a homely, northern farmer, with a stubborn countenance, and stalwart limbs set out to advantage in knee-breeches and gaiters. Such an individual seated in his arm-chair, his mug of ale frothing on the round table before him, is to be seen in any circuit of five or six miles among these hills, if you go at the right time after dinner.

I looked up the verb in two dictionaries, yet methinks it does not mean 'to benefit somebody' or 'to provide with an advantage' in this context.
What does advantage mean in this context?

Why was this migrated? It's patently nothing to do with Learning English.

I’m voting to close this question because the question about English usage in a 19th century novel is unrelated to Learning English and off topic. It would be better on [english.se] or [literature.se]

The prepositional phrase "to advantage" is still used nowadays.  You can check Google Books for "shown to advantage".

@TimR I checked Ngrams because you said "to advantage" is still used today, but the quote has the phrasal verb construction  set out to advantage not "shown" And if we include "used to advantage" we get a better perspective as to their popularity. Can we at least agree the phrasing in the original quotation is hardly used nowadays, and is antiquated? Can we?

@Mari-LouA  I think the antiquated clothing is coloring your judgment.  "to advantage" is not antiquated, and neither is "set out" in the sense of "displayed, presented".   I've read a lot of older texts in my day, 8th century onwards, so perhaps I have a longer view than most.  I could be convinced that as a collocation "set out to advantage" has seen its heyday, but it is not "antiquated".

@TimR  To clarify, I was referring to "set out to advantage" as being antiquated and the linked Ngram chart appears to support my idea.

@Mari-LouA Sorry, I think you're being too AI-like. Consider, for example, that the Cambridge dictionary glosses set off to advantage.

@TimR I am AI-like? Why do you say that? Never mind, it's new put-down that I will add in my mental drawer.   There's a reason why I didn't say "obsolete" or "archaic"… the phrase, however, is rarely used nowadays, in modern texts or in speech. Of course there's always going to be someone who will write or say "set out to advantage" but it would sound very formal, would it not?

@MariLoudA The individual pieces of the phrase, the phrasal verb and the prepositional phrase, are still in use today with the same meanings.  Don't parse it as a collocation but simply as those pieces put together!  That's what I meant by "too AI-like" -- settling on an approach that boxes you in and not knowing  that there's no need for the box.  I do accept that "to advantage" is a tad fustian. But in the right context it would be fine.

North Michigan University Writing Center advises:

Don’t confuse a [to-]infinitiv[al] [clause] with a prepositional
phrase beginning with “to.” Prepositional phrases consist of “to” plus
a [standard] noun [or] pronoun or any modifiers.

'Freely associating' prepositional phrases are usually easy to spot (even when they're not italicised for teaching purposes) ... though they do occur in different places in sentences:

She went to the shops yesterday.
Behind the door is a silly place to stand.
On the recently discovered painting was the unmistakeable signature of Leonardo.
He hid behind a rock.
They're often found under trees.
After the war, rationing was still needed for quite a few years.

But prepositions are also used in metaphorical (more or less peripheral) ways, not just the central locative, directional (together 'spatial') and temporal ways. These are often still easy to spot ('They are now on the train,' 'The forest is on fire'). They are fixed phrases, usually idioms. Note that a determiner may precede the noun complementing the preposition.
The preposition to is (probably thankfully) not used in many phraseme to-phrases. Most are fairly transparent Here is a list; it's not claimed to be exhaustive. These fixed to-phrases are often used to modify a verb:

to a certain extent
to a T
to advantage
to bits
to the bitter end
to boot [= 'also', not a verb-modifier]
to [the] death
to distraction
to glory [used as a complement, 'gone to glory']
to God [irreverent?; intensifier after verb 'hope' say]
to hand [used as a complement, 'do we have a timer to hand?']
to heel [of a dog say; adverbial … or exclamation]
to hell [irreverent?; intensifier after suitable verb]
to horse [often an interjection: = 'Mount up!']
to my mind
to one's liking [used as a complement]
to order
to perfection
to pot
to scale [used as a complement, 'Is your map roughly to scale?'?]
to size [used as a complement]
to taste [used as a complement]
to the bad / good [used as a complement]
to the contrary [= 'I must disagree with that statement' etc; not a verb-modifier]
to the dogs
to the limit

A complication arises in that another usage of 'to' (some might claim it's even a different word) exists, the infinitive marker. When related words (ie not homographs in the classical sense, having totally different etymologies) which manifest different parts of speech are spelled the same, some call them intercategorial polysemes. This implies different senses of a single lexeme. So prepositional 'to' and infinitive-marker 'to' qualify. 'To' can introduce to-infinitival clauses as well as to-prepositional phrases:

John has gone uptown to shop.
This place has gone to pot.

This would cause few difficulties were it not for the fact that some words appearing after 'to' can be either nouns or verbs: another type of intercategorial polysemy. Of the examples listed in the to-prepositional phrases (we can of course ignore say 'limit' occurring after a determiner), glory, hand, heel, order, pot, scale and taste, and more rarely advantage, boot, and size, have verb intercategorial polysemes. One has to be aware of this, and to be careful to parse correctly. Often, context will disambiguate:

Add nutmeg to taste. [prepositional phrase meaning 'to your liking']
She poured out a little of the wine to taste. [to-infinitival clause of purpose].

'... stalwart limbs [which were] set out to advantage [in such and such a way]' must  use the prepositional phrase 'to advantage', meaning 'optimally', as others have said, as 'advantage' is (when a verb) a transitive verb, and there is no sign of a direct object.

An overly long, complicated to follow answer, using linguistic terms (e.g. phraseme to-phrases) that the vast majority of English learners will not have heard nor ever need.

It could provide inspiration for a linguist-to-be or two; linguistic terminology needs to be precise (I wish linguists themselves would form a consensus) ... and I refuse to dumb down. Yes, it's an ELU answer, but a comprehensive question would be suitable for ELU. The enquirer seems happy with the answer.

Funny, an EL&U answer for a question that was originally posted there but was migrated by three users, one of whom was you. P.S. Writing in plain good English is not dumbing down.

I would move your final remarks about transitive verbs needing an object to the top of the answer.  In situations where the verb is transitive only, it is a far more elegant way for a learner to parse such a sentence than consulting, brute-force, a list of prepositional phrases looking for a match.

I don't like the reorganisation on style / developmental grounds, but I've highlighted the part you mention. Someone will probably complain about the noise now.

@Mari-LouA I agree completely. When learning a language, one doesn't need a linguistic epistle or treatise.

Highlighing is fine, but I am not sure that I grasp your meaning when you say that you don't like the relocation of the remarks re transitive verbs needing an object to the top on "style / developmental grounds".  Pedagogically?

I would also point out, pedagogically, that "there is no sign of an object" could cause a learner to stumble.  "There is no sign of {something}" if not an idiom, at least requires a subtle knowledge of the word sign.  I say this only because as a denizen of ELU you might be used to a more advanced readership.

@Mari-Lou A 'Funny, an EL&U answer for a question that was originally posted there but was migrated by three users, one of whom was you. ' False. I voted on closure on the grounds of not using a dictionary proficiently, valid on ELU. But there is a retrievable ELU question, looking at the possible confusion between to-infinitival clauses and prepositional to-phrases. There are so few fixed (often idiomatic) to-phrases that a near-exhaustive list is achievable. Even CGEL present such lists.

@Tim R I confess that a list of non-free association (so ignoring to the station / to school / to the doctor's ...) to-phrases has been something I wanted to see recorded for quite a time. (This question also nicely brought out the possible confusion with to-infinitival clauses.) And this seemed the best place so far; I was disappointed to see it migrated (and CV-d on 'lack of shown reasonable dictionary research' grounds to try to get it re-opened later on ELU.  Migration to ELL is one way.

@EdwinAshworth when you se two votes in favour of migration and vote that the question could be answered by a dictionary, you're voting in favour of migration.  You know how this works better than anyone. Oh, the OP did in fact check with a dictionary, in fact two dictionaries. The close notice reads: Questions that can be easily answered by consulting a reputable online dictionary should be closed with this reason unless the question includes an explanation of why the dictionary wasn't helpful.…. which is exactly what the OP did. Yet, you voted to close it.

Proficient use of a dictionary on ELU would show the noun form, and give a quote.

@EdwinAshworth    See James K's observation underneath the OP's question. But I don't think the question can be migrated twice, back to EL&U where it belongs. Maybe you can find out, when you have the time. A belated Merry Christmas, and a Happy New Year from the heart. I quite like you, and your droll sense of humour. :)

Yes, a Merry Christmastime; we've just had our annual antihumbug injection of Michael Caine as Scrooge, and there are more important things in life than to-phrases. I appreciate that we often come at things from different angles. I'd say that 'It is not a verb' is pared down to the point of being misleading, for instance. And my answer is certainly too comprehensive for all but a very few learners. But it's the only sort of answer I'd be happy with. // I've flagged a request for a remigration. We'll see. // Again, a  profitable New Year :)

It is not a verb.
The breeches and gaiters showed his legs to advantage - they made them look good. See this definition.

From the OED:

advantage noun
Phrases
P.1.
P.1.a.   to advantage.
P.1.a.ii.   So as to increase or augment the effect of anything; advantageously, favourably. 1604–
[selected attestations]
1935    A spacious lawn is enclosed by yew hedges,
against which the bloom of Scotch laburnum shows up to advantage.
—Times 23 May 13/1 1974     She was pretty
and her figure had been shown to advantage in the swimsuit. —R. L.
Hill, Nails xvii. 175
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login required)

